How do I clear all auto fill data from these text boxes in Tauri?
I still can't find a place to delete historical data, including in the Microsoft Edge DevTools. Please help me!
enter image description here
On this page, I pressed the F12 key to enter the debugging tool interface, but I couldn't find the function to clear these data.
I know that autocomplete="off" can be added to the input tag, but removing this attribute will still result in all previously entered all auto fill data remaining.

That auto-fill is provided by the webview and not tauri. If you want to actually delete the data one of the answers here should help: Deleting autocomplete entries in Microsoft Edge
